# how to reload a partial view on success of a function that is defined in factory

Tags: angularjs

I want to reload a webpage on success of a function. I'd like not to loose the cookie data upon reload too. I don't know how to achieve this as I have defined the function using factory in my controller.

JavaScript Code

```
'use strict';
angular.module('employees', ['ngTable']);

//Routers

//Factories
myApp.factory('employeeServices', ['$http', function($http) {
    var factoryDefinitions = {
        moveToBench: function(employeeId) {
            return $http.post(myApp.IndecommBaseUrl + '/Workflow?entityId=' + employeeId + '&nextStateId=' + myApp.state.bench)
                .success(function(data) {
                $route.reload();
            });
        }
    }
    return factoryDefinitions;
}]);
//Controllers
myApp.controller('getEmployeesController', ['$scope', 'employeeServices', 'dataTable', function($scope, employeeServices, dataTable) {
    employeeServices.getEmployees().then(function(result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
        if (!result.data.error) {
            dataTable.render($scope, '', "employeesList", result.data);
        }
        $scope.moveToBench = function(id) {
            employeeServices.moveToBench(id);
        }
    });
}]);
```

I want the refresh to happen on success of the function 'moveToBench'.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the reload not working? Or the factory is not even called? This is how i do my reloads: $window.location.reload();

Comment: @GustavoGabriel: please post it as answer.

Comment: @naveen ok posted it..

Comment: Don't refresh the entire window, you're going to reset the Angular session. Use `$route.reload()` will reload the current route, which is likely what you actually want. You already have this  in your service code. I would move that to your controller, such that you do `employeeServices.moveToBench(id).then(() => $route.reload())`.

Comment: Note also that the native Angular router is widely considered deprecated. Consider using the Angular Component Router (from angular 2) or ui-router

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I will tryout all the given answers and mark the correct one... Thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the reload not working? Or the factory is not even called? Anyway, This is how I do my reloads:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Give it a try to see if it works =)

Comment: also inject `$window` dependency on the factory +1

Comment: This is a bad idea, unless you have some of maintaining the user's session you're going to lose all of that information if you reload the window itself

Comment: Rule #1 of Programming: Don't assume that what the user says they want is what they actually want.. It is very likely OP does not actually want to reload the webpage and even if he did it would be a bad idea (interrupt user flow, for one, which is against the idea of a SPA). OP definitely needs to clarify, sure

Comment: I agree  100% with you but I cant read his mind, Im relying on what he said through his question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, If reloading the entire page is a bad idea. shld I try to reload just the partial view?

Comment: It will depend on what you want...If you dont mind lose some information already saved on the page you can do a full reload..